# Can you get files off-line?

Tags: american-english

Often times I hear people say "I got it offline" to mean they downloaded it from the internet, is this an accepted term or should it be "I got it online"?

Comment: A variant I have also heard: "I got it off of online".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In isolation, *I got it offline* is probably incorrect, but I can imagine contexts where it would be correct.

In standard usage, *online* means *on or connected to the internet* (or, more rarely, *intranet* etc.), and *offline* means *not connected to the internet*, or just *on a local computer (whether or not it’s connected)*.

So since when you download a file you must be connected to the net, it would be more usual/correct to say you *got it online*.

However, think about how *they got the groceries home* can mean *they (purchased the groceries elsewhere and then) brought them home*.  Analogously, I could imagine someone saying *Normally I work with my spreadsheet online, but I got it offline this morning so I could work on the plane.*  In this context, *I got it offline* is being used clearly and not unreasonably to mean downloading something — getting it from online to offline.  But this example is a little contrived; in most situations, it should be *I got it online*.

Comment: When I read "I got it offline", my first interpretation is that the person got the information while browsing offline. So, with more context, Person A: "Ah, you read the article. Did you click the link to read the follow-up?" Person B: "No, I got it offline, so I couldn't click the link."

Comment: @Mitch: yes, I’d agree.

Answer (score 5):

"Off-line" is generally accepted to mean "not connected to a network".

You can download files while online* and you can store those files in offline* storage.

*both of these terms are used without the hyphen. For example, Firefox has an option called "Work offline" under the File menu.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that to convey the meaning correctly, you either *got a file from an online resource* or else you *downloaded a file for offline access*. "Got a file offline" as an isolated expression to me sounds like you deleted an online resource. For example: I put a few racy pictures of myself online, but now that I think things through, it'd be best if I got them offline.

Casually, perhaps go with that you *got it off the internet*.